# Slider inside a form - Input and TextArea elements are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, materialize

**[JsFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesss/akn9baz3/1/)**

This question is about the MaterializeCSS frontend framework. I am trying to use a `.carousel` (see [source](http://materializecss.com/carousel.html) for more information) inside a `<form>` element. The effect I need is a slider containing different input fields of the form.

The problem is that the text fields and text area elements somehow don't get activated when the user clicks on them.

Here is a SSCCE:

***HTML:***

```
<section class="row" >

<div class="card hoverable medium indigo darken-4 col l8 offset-l2 m12 s12">
    <div class="card-content">

            <form id="createForm" action="" method="get">

                <div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
                    <div class="carousel-item white-text">

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <input type="text" id="idInput" class="validate" />
                            <label for="idInput">ID</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <input type="text" id="nameInput" class="validate" />
                            <label for="nameInput">Name</label>
                        </div>

                        <div class="input-field">
                            <textarea id="descriptionInput" class="materialize-textarea validate"></textarea>
                            <label for="descriptionInput">Desc</label>
                        </div>

                    </div><!--.carousel-item-->


                    <div class="carousel-item white-text">Carousel Item Two</div><!--.carousel-item-->


                    <div class="carousel-item white-text">Carousel Item Three</div><!--.carousel-item-->
                </div><!--.carousel-->

            </form>


    </div><!--.card-content-->
</div><!--card-->

</section>
```

***JS:***

```
$(".carousel").carousel({
        fullWidth : true,
        noWrap : true
    });
```

Comment: The Problem is when you write the forms input in carousels the js is not able to find it during initialization as they are wrapped inside carousel which is rendered little late.
You can verify this by manually traversing to the input field and making it active using jquery.

Comment: You can check it here on this Codepen https://codepen.io/nirajtech/pen/JJOrjb?editors=1010

Comment: Click on the last name to check it.

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Can you please write that as an answer, so that I can mark it as the accepted answer. That will help someone in future. @Niraj

Comment: @Niraj Hey there is a problem. Even after the **`active`** class is added to the `input`, and `textarea` elements, they are not capable of receiving user input. That is, when I start typing on the keyboard, the text is Not written to the screen. Please try typing after activating the input element in your codepen example?

Comment: Ya i tried it, trying to solve that issue!!

Comment: @Niraj Started an issue [here on Github.](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/4905)